# what package do I need to use clang with asan for 32 bit?

Tags: package, clang, sanitizer, address-sanitizer

I get this error when compiling with clang++ and `-fsanitize=address -m32`:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/llvm-3.6/bin/../lib/clang/3.6.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-i386.a: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/llvm-3.6/bin/../lib/clang/3.6.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan_cxx-i386.a: No such file or directory
```

What package do I need? I already tried with `libclang-3.6-dev`

I also got an error for clang 3.7 with `-m64`:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/llvm-3.7/bin/../lib/clang/3.7.1/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.a: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/llvm-3.7/bin/../lib/clang/3.7.1/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan_cxx-x86_64.a: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With clang 3.7 this seems to be a known problem, see https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22757.
With clang 3.6 I could link without a problem.

On Ubuntu these installation instructions worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/509223

Comment: thanks for tracking that clang 3.7/3.8 issue down!
but the problem for 3.6 and 32 bit builds remains... I think I need ```libclang-3.6-dev:i386``` which is not whitelisted on travis-ci and I've reported that to them. Anyway thanks